# Manipulating Spotify Play Button via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotify

Is it possible to manipulate the Spotify Play Button via jQuery? For instance, pausing and playing, changing the song, etc? I've tried to modify the contents of the iframe in which the Play Button resides by using .contents() but haven't had much luck. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Spotify Play Button doesn't expose a JS Api to control playback.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how they accomplish this technically? As in, why can't I manipulate the contents of that iframe with javascript? And how does that iframe communicate with the Spotify window?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. There is definitely something they have in place blocking JQuery from manipulating the contents of the page, whether intentional or not. It may be a same-origin policy type thing, but I don't know. I will post here if I figure something out to help you out.