# Controlling the Spotify Play Button in website

Tags: media-player, spotify

I want to control the play and pause and of the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) I have integrated in a website. Is there a way to do it? For example, if I want to start playing a song by clicking an element on the page, at the moment users still need to press the play button in the Spotify player. Is it possible to skip this step and play the song immediately?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the Spotify Play Button doesn't expose any interface to control it. See [Manipulating Spotify Play Button via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799944/manipulating-spotify-play-button-via-jquery). Thus, the user as to click on the play button to start plying a track.

Comment: I needed to do this too - I ended up switching to the SoundCloud API which allows for control via the parent page.